# LILYGO TTGO T-Display cannot detect MPU 6050 Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Temperature Sensor

Tags: i2c, esp32, nodemcu, display, mpu6050

I've been trying to connect a MPU 6050 Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Temperature Sensor to a LILYGO TTGO T-Display to get readings displayed on the serial monitor (for starters). The wiring is pretty straightforward. I need to power up the MPU6050 with 3V, and connect the SDA and SCL. I followed this tutorial (https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-mpu-6050-accelerometer-gyroscope-arduino/).

This is the code used:

```
#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Wire.h>

Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial)
    delay(10); // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until serial console opens

  Serial.println("Adafruit MPU6050 test!");

  // Try to initialize!
  if (!mpu.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find MPU6050 chip");
    while (1) {
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("MPU6050 Found!");

  mpu.setAccelerometerRange(MPU6050_RANGE_8_G);
  Serial.print("Accelerometer range set to: ");
  switch (mpu.getAccelerometerRange()) {
  case MPU6050_RANGE_2_G:
    Serial.println("+-2G");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_4_G:
    Serial.println("+-4G");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_8_G:
    Serial.println("+-8G");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_16_G:
    Serial.println("+-16G");
    break;
  }
  mpu.setGyroRange(MPU6050_RANGE_500_DEG);
  Serial.print("Gyro range set to: ");
  switch (mpu.getGyroRange()) {
  case MPU6050_RANGE_250_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 250 deg/s");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_500_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 500 deg/s");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_1000_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 1000 deg/s");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_2000_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 2000 deg/s");
    break;
  }

  mpu.setFilterBandwidth(MPU6050_BAND_5_HZ);
  Serial.print("Filter bandwidth set to: ");
  switch (mpu.getFilterBandwidth()) {
  case MPU6050_BAND_260_HZ:
    Serial.println("260 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_184_HZ:
    Serial.println("184 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_94_HZ:
    Serial.println("94 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_44_HZ:
    Serial.println("44 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_21_HZ:
    Serial.println("21 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_10_HZ:
    Serial.println("10 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_5_HZ:
    Serial.println("5 Hz");
    break;
  }

  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  /* Get new sensor events with the readings */
  sensors_event_t a, g, temp;
  mpu.getEvent(&a, &g, &temp);

  /* Print out the values */
  Serial.print("Acceleration X: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.z);
  Serial.println(" m/s^2");

  Serial.print("Rotation X: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.z);
  Serial.println(" rad/s");

  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temp.temperature);
  Serial.println(" degC");

  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}
```

The pinout config for the TTGO T Display is shown below:
[image]

I connected the pins based on this as follows:

TTGO        MPU6050

3V  ---->  Vcc

G   ---->  Gnd

22  ---->  SCL

21  ---->  SDA

But I keep getting the following error on the serial monitor.

```
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1324
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:13508
load:0x40080400,len:3604
entry 0x400805f0
Adafruit MPU6050 test!
Failed to find MPU6050 chip
```

What is strange is that the MPU 6050 works perfectly fine with the same pin connection on the normal Node MCU ESP 32 system. Any idea why it won't work on the TTGO?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error (Failed to find MPU6050 chip)on the same program with the same tutorial. I thought it was this, that, and an act of nature. I hade proven the MPU6050 worked fine and the ESP32 worked fine. EVENTUALLY I realised it was dead simple, the ESP32 ( a cheapo one) had different pinout to the one in the tutorial, SCL,SDA and 3.3v were in the wrong place even though the red LED illuminated on my MPU6050 board. Anyway I wired it correctly and it works just fine and the Webserver one too. I did not do the display one! ( Don't take anything for granted). I do not know which incarnation of the MPU6050 you are using but when using mine (looked identical as the one in the tutorial) on an ESP8266 the I2C addressing was a bit finicky and I had to take the address connection hard to GND  with a wire to get it to run consistently, that too caused the same error (Failed to find MPU6050 chip).